# Makefile rule that doesn't generate a file, but checks dependecy

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How do I write an intermediate rule that doesn't generate a target file in Makefile in such a way that it checks dependency correctly?

So I have something like this:

```
install_script: xxx.sql
     psql -f $?

dump.txt: install_script
     psql -c 'select * from xxx;' > $@
```

I want to make sure that `install_script` only get run when `make dump.txt` if and only if `xxx.sql` was modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the simplest way for your case is to use a dummy intermediate file:

```
.xxx.sql.timestamp: xxx.sql
    psql -f $?
    @touch $@

dump.txt: .xxx.sql.timestamp
    psql -c 'select * from xxx;' > $@
```

And if you want to force dumping the query result unconditionally (even if everything is up-to-date), then add `.PHONY` target:

```
.PHONY : dump.txt
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

You probably are looking for the [phony targets](http://wiki.osdev.org/Makefile) in the makefile.
So it should look like:

```
.PHONY: dump.txt
dump.txt: install_script
```